# Pie with legend

Tags: matlab, plot, legend, pie-chart

I want to add legend to matlab pie instead of just putting the names close the pie itself. That is, I want names to be displayed in a box, and the percentage to be displayed close to the pie (as it usually is). But if I simply add a legend, as follows, it will be not attached to the patches information:

```
pieH=pie([.3,.4,.3]);
legend({'Leg1','Leg2','Leg3'},'location','EastOutside');
```

[image: Pie legend malfunction]

I've tried turning the patch annotation icon display to on, as follows, but it didn't work:

```
set(get(get(pieH(1),'Annotation'),'LegendInformation'),'IconDisplayStyle','on')
set(get(get(pieH(3),'Annotation'),'LegendInformation'),'IconDisplayStyle','on')
set(get(get(pieH(5),'Annotation'),'LegendInformation'),'IconDisplayStyle','on')
```

I also tried passing the patched handles, as it says in the help, also with no effect:

```
legend([pieH(1:2:end)],{'Leg1','Leg2','Leg3'},'location','EastOutside');
```

---

**Edit**

I was using matlab handle graphics version 2, and it seems that this combinations does not work yet at new graphics version. Since it is a matlab bug and this topic led me to the discovering, I am closing it. But if someone, by chance, already had this issue and knows how to workaround please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's a way to make it work:

```
X=[100 200 300];
h=pie(X);
legend(h(1:2:end), 'Small', 'Medium', 'Large','location','EastOutside');
```

[image]

Comment: +1 if for some reason the order of the handles returned is different, you could perhaps do it as: `legend(findobj(h, 'type','patch'), {'1','2','3'}, 'Location','EastOutside')`

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your help, at least I know that it's not my fault hehe.

Comment: @Werner: oh I see, it seems HG2 still have some bugs that needs to be fixed... Digging a bit here, I think the problem has to do with the "data binding" between the color in the legend and the color of the pie patches.

Comment: @Amro If you can dig it out I would gladly give you a bounty for that (+100 because I am poor rep guy hahaha).